# passing EditText value through putExtra()

Tags: android

how can i assign value of EditText to a string?
I want to pass this value to an another activity through putExtras().

### my code is :

```
 EditText txtquantity=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
```

### quantity_bundle.putString("quantity",txtquantity.getText());

when I am doing like this an error is occured.
Please give me the solution...
Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getText() on a EditText object returns the Text as an Editable call toString() to get the actual text.

```
quantity_bundle.putString("quantity",txtquantity.getText().toString());
```

Comment: `getText()` returns `CharSequence`, not a `TextView`. This code also may be used: 
    quantity_bundle.putCharSequence("quantity",txtquantity.getText());

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it using Intent's put Extra() method.

intent.putExtra ( "TextBox", editText.getText().toString() );